# Express and parser

Tags: node.js, express

I want to build a website, where user can press a button and nodeJS will start parsing process of some site (using PhantomJS hedless browser) and then return result to the user. I'm planning to use a static page with support of sockets, so user will get instant response as soon as parsing process will finish running. The process of parsing page with use of PhantomJS is kind of slow, so it'll take some time to run. My question is:

Is it normal to run the parser from the same nodeJS process (express)? What about preformance, when a bunch of people will press the button at the same time, should i be worried about that?

Or maybe i should separate 2 processes (parser and express) and somehow make them communicate them with each other?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would want to use Child processes in Node. [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)